# Mouse Handling in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mouseevent

Is there any way in matlab to do mouse event handling like click handling?

I need it to develop an application where I'm displaying an image in matlab's imshow. 
Once user clicks at a particular point on image, I need to know co-ordinates of that point and use them for later processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture clicks, you have to define the `ButtonDownFcn` property of your [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image_props.html). The callback can then read the `CurrentPoint` property of the [AXES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html) and thus determine the coordinates.

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at [GINPUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html) if you want the user to select a fixed number of points.

Comment: Thanx @Jonas: For future reference to anyone reading this answer...

The ginput function opens an empty graph where you can click on any point to get the co-ordinate...

To use ginput on user defined image simply do this::
imshow(image); % shows the image where you want to mark...
[x y] = ginput(1); % to get one point on image ..